# Как прочитать и вывести каждую строку из файла? C++

Tags: c++, qt

Как прочитать и вывести каждую строку из файла?
Имеется такой код:

```
ifstream log(Str+"\\log.txt");
do
   {
     string asd;
     getline(log,asd);
     cout << asd << endl;
   }while(???);
log.close();
```

Но он, естественно, не работает.

Comment: вместо вопросительных знаков log, но вариант в ответе BogdanBida лучше

Comment: при чем тут Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сколько я помню, можно делать так:

```
string asd;
while(getline(log,asd)) {
       cout << asd << endl;
}
```

Comment: конечно так и нужно